# Creating sharable Resource Drawables without static must be possible what am I missing?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I'm pretty far along in a project and have hit an undesirable snag and unable to find a solution.  I have some sudo code that I believe will illustrate what I am trying to do but is not full code.  The error is NullPointerException on the ContextWrapper in the Main class when attempting to pass it to an ImageHandler.  Unfortunately, ImageViews and I suspect all Views, try to resolve their drawables before an activity has called the onCreate.  So I had to try and store images into the Activity Constructor but then I am unable to pass the context.  I have considered AsyncTask or the handler to wait for the onCreate() of the activity but then I might as well go back to SurfaceView and creating my own designs.  I will continue to look but if someone with more android experience then me knows of either better design or the solution the help would be tremendous.  Also the eclipse layout previewer being compatible is highly preferred.  I have also tried to have each imageview independently have the desired layerdrawables even though alot of them are the same but the performance is terrible.  Had to add the constructor in the Activity because if the imagehandler is created in the onCreate it will be null when the the ImageView tries to call it on it's constructor.  Why the Activities components ready themselves before Activity.onCreate is called is something  I don't quite understand yet.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageHandler ih;

MainActivity(){
            Log.d("Acitivity", "Constructed");
    ih=new ImageHandler(this);
    //ih=new ImageHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
    //ih=new ImageHandler(this.getBaseContext());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d("Activity", "Created");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public LayerDrawable getImage(int some_identifier){
    return ih.getImage(some_identifier);
}

 }
```

===================

```
 public class ImageHandler {
LayerDrawable[] image;

ImageHandler(Context context){
            Log.d("ImageView", "Constructed");
    //manipulate resource images to create custom layerdrawables and store.     

    //originally attempted to create a layer.xml and although it worked
    //in the emulator perfectly the behavior was quite different in live tests.
    //although it made sense any change to layer.xml images was global for all who used it
    //the strange behavior was that the emulator behaved as desired.
}


public LayerDrawable getImage(int identifier){
    return image[identifier];
}
 }
```

====================

```
 public class SomeImageView extends ImageView{

public SomeImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    int some_identifier=0;
    this.setImageDrawable(((MainActivity)context).getImage(some_identifier));
}

 }
```

Thanks again community for any help.

Comment: why do you have a constructor for MainActivity remove it and move this inside onCreate `ih=new ImageHandler(this);`

Comment: When I do that the error is NullPointer in the ImageView because the ImageView resolves it's constructor before the Activity is created

Comment: where is `SomeImageView` constructor invoked from? you should not create a constructor of activity class.

Comment: SomeImageView is invoked in the layout.  I made edits to show that both activity and imageview are constructed then the activity is created.  It is desirable to be able to use the CustomLayoutView tab in eclipses layout graphical interface.  Image identifiers are passed with custom resource attributes in attr.xml.

Comment: I've gotten this to work with a layout.xml as I mentioned above however changes to the images only works in the emulator and in live any change affects all imageview.

Comment: The `Context` of an `Activity` is valid starting from the `onCreate()` method so in the `onCreate()` method create/initialize the `ImageHandler` object and after that set the content view of your layout. Don't hold static references to drawables.

Comment: @Luksprog it's possible I had the code after I set the contentView though I don't believe so, but I will try again to see.

Comment: It seems it was the placement thanks Luksprog!!